# error during connect: ... http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client on any docker command with remote host

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to connect to remote docker host through ssh tunnel. I have forwarded the `2375` port and I'm trying to connect to it by specifying `DOCKER_HOST`.

```
$ DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.24 DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2375 docker ps
error during connect: Get https://localhost:2375/v1.24/containers/json: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

This have worked before, but I can't make it work again, because my docker client keep giving me back this error. I can't make it ignore the https/http stuff. The connection is OK, i can curl the endpoints just fine, its just that docker client is doing something and then preventing itself from connecting and I don't know how to make it ignore the https.

Comment: Port 2375 is usually http (unsecured) and 2376 is secured https (SSL/TLS). It is not clear from this example what the remote port is (you only show the localhost port). Try using remote port 2376 if you aren't already.

Comment: @DanLowe I figured it out. I had `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` set in env.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have finally figured out why I was getting this error. I was positive `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY` was not set, but it was. So if anyone get this error, make sure the env variable is undefined or that the value is empty.

using

```
$ DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.24 DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2375 DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY= docker ps
```

did work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this! I needed that `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=` which was non-obvious at first :/